# Creating 'public functions' in Django / Accessing Model data from current template in template tag

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm in the process of learning Django and i'm converting a site from Laravel to Django to help me learn.

In Laravel i had a code snippet of:

```
public function attr_profile($label)
{
    $attr = space_to_underscore($label);
    if ($this->$attr >= 90) {
        echo '<li>'.$label.'<span class="pull-right label label-highest">'.$this->$attr.'</span></li>';
    } elseif ($this->$attr < 90 && $this->$attr >= 80) {
        echo '<li>'.$label.'<span class="pull-right label label-high">'.$this->$attr.'</span></li>';
    } elseif ($this->$attr < 80 && $this->$attr >= 65) {
        echo '<li>'.$label.'<span class="pull-right label label-normal">'.$this->$attr.'</span></li>';
    } elseif ($this->$attr < 65 && $this->$attr >= 65) {
        echo '<li>'.$label.'<span class="pull-right label label-low">'.$this->$attr.'</span></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li>'.$label.'<span class="pull-right label label-lowest">'.$this->$attr.'</span></li>';
    }
}
```

Which let me use:

```
{{ $player->attr_profile('Ball Control') }}
{{ $player->attr_profile('Curve') }}
```

In the template and it would spit out:

```
<li>Ball Control<span class="pull-right label label-highest">95</span></li>
<li>Curve<span class="pull-right label label-high">88</span></li>
```

I'm trying to repeat the same in Django in the most DRY way i can. The closest i have got is creating a custom template tag.

```
# Core imports
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.simple_tag
def attr_profile(label):
    attr = label.replace(" ", "_").lower()
    return '<li>' + label + '<span class="pull-right label label-highest">' + attr + '</span></li>'
```

But ideally i'd like to be able to spit out 'self.attr' or 'player.attr' like how i could use '$this->attr' in Laravel

I've tried numerous attempts but fall flat on my face each time. Are template tags the best way to do this, if so how do i go about using the existing model on the original template? The template is built from:

```
class PlayerDetailView(DetailView):
    # Define the model for the CBV
    model = Player
```

If that helps

Comment: Why not directly refer to the player's attributes in the templates like `{{ object.ball_control }}` ?

Comment: I could but then i would need to wrap each attribute in the 5 if tag's would i not? Each object is between 0-99 and gets a different CSS class based on the rating it falls between

Comment: To better illustrate with code, I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#include) tag for template snippets  and avoid the use of template tags.

```
{% include "label_snippet.html" with label="Ball Control" score=object.ball_control %}
```

The contents of `label_snippet.html` could be:

```
{% if score >= 90 %}
<li>{{ label }}<span class="pull-right label label-highest">{{ score }}</span></li>
{% elif score < 90 and score >= 80 %}
....
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I had no idea this was possible answers exactly what i needed! Thank you very much :)